# How to get the AppDispatch Typescript type in redux toolkit when store is initialized with a function?

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

Today my `AppDispatch` type is extracted from `store.dispatch`:

```js
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import auth from "./auth/authSlice";
const rootReducer = combineReducers({ auth });
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer
});
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export default store;
```

Now I try to replace store with initStore function. I want to rehydrate my store using preloadedState.

```js
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import auth from "./auth/authSlice";
const rootReducer = combineReducers({ auth });
const store = (preloadedState={}) => {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    preloadedState,
  });
}
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch;
export default store;
```

I have an error:

```
Property 'dispatch' does not exist on type '(preloadedState?: {}) => EnhancedStore<CombinedState<{ auth: AuthState; }>, AnyAction, [ThunkMiddleware<CombinedState<{ auth: AuthState; }>, AnyAction, null> | ThunkMiddleware<...>]>'.ts(2339)
```

How can I get the AppDispatch type correctly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've changed `store` from being an actual Redux store instance to "a function that returns a Redux store", without fixing the rest of your code to match that.  So, the first issue is that `typeof store.dispatch;` won't work at that point in the code, because `store` is a function and not an actual store instance.

Beyond that, I'm not sure how you'd actually manage to get the type of `dispatch` here because you haven't created a store yet when the type is being defined.  I suppose you *could* try something like this, but I don't know if it'll work:

```
const initStore = (preloadedState={}) => {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    preloadedState,
  });
}
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>;
export type AppDispatch = ReturnType<typeof initStore>["dispatch"];
export default initStore ;
```